# Can't delete Business Rules in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015, business-rules

I am trying to delete a business rule, but I keep getting the error:

"The record could not be deleted because of an association - The record cannot be deleted because it is associated with another record."

I have checked dependencies using "Show Dependencies" button, and there are no association that can prevent deletion.

I am working with CRM 2015 on cloud.

Could someone please advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After removing all of the conditions and actions here are two things you could try:

1. Create a new solution, add the entity and select the "add related entities"
2. Export the solution and use the [SolutionPackager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602987.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to "Unpack" the components so you can take a look at the XAML to see if there's anything suspicious

Sample SolutionPackager usage:

```
SolutionPackager.exe /action:extract /allowWrite:Yes  /zipfile:C:\Work\Exports\MySolution.zip /folder:"C:\Work\Exports\MySolution"
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Looks like it's a defect. I am working with MS Support on this.